# onSaveUser event - cannot redirect or access errors

Tags: plugin-development, usermodel, redirection

I've written a plugin which intercepts the `user.onSaveUser` event.

However if the save fails the user is still redirected to the page specified in the 'redirect' parameter/field of the form. How do I redirect them back to the form with errors and then access those errors?

I've tried `craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables()` but still being returned to the page/URL specified in the original form. If I remove the redirect field from the front-end form I am redirected to the form on error but cannot access the errors sent in `craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables()`.

Any thoughts on how to specify the redirect destination depending on success/fail and also how to send/access the offending error messages in my original template?

Answer (score 1):

As your code is running during an event, returning the request to the page has to be done a bit more explicitly than when you are performing similar behavior in a controller.

While I'm probably not the best person to explain this in detail, the code below gives one example I was provided in how you can set your route variables and end the request:

```
if ($errors)
{
    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'errors' => $errors
    ));

    $route = craft()->urlManager->parseUrl(craft()->request);
    craft()->runController($route);
    craft()->end();
}
```